# jQuery slideDown() function doesn't work for both elements after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make an animation using the `slideDown()` function and somehow, `.quote-container` isn't included in it, even if the `slideDown()` function contains `.quote-container` and `#new-quote` elements.

Why do they work in the first load animation and in the second one (after the click event), don't (only the `#new-quote` works)? `.quote-container` is only displayed after the slideDown() animation end, which is 2 seconds.

```js
// slideDown() works only for #new-quote
$("#new-quote").on("click", function() {
  $(".quote-container, #new-quote").slideUp(2000, function() {
    $(".quote-container, #new-quote")
      .css("display", "inline-block")
      .hide();

    $(".quote-container, #new-quote").slideDown(2000);
  });
});

// slideDown() for both elements works
var height = $(".quote-container").outerHeight();
$(".quote-container, #new-quote")
  .css("display", "inline-block")
  .hide();
$("#new-quote").css("height", height + 80);
$(".quote-container").css("padding", "2.5rem");
$(".quote-container, #new-quote").slideDown(2000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.v-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.v-wrap:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.quote-container {
  width: 31.25rem;
  background: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  display: none;
}

.quote-text {
  font-size: 1.625rem;
}

.quote-text i {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}

.quote-text p {
  display: inline;
}

.quote-author {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0.4rem 2rem 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.button:not(#new-quote) {
  min-width: 1rem;
  min-height: 1rem;
}

.button:hover:not(#new-quote) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.button i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#new-quote {
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.25625rem;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0 .75rem;
  display: none;
}

#new-quote:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#new-quote:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

footer a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="v-wrap">
  <div class="quote-container">
    <div class="quote-text">
    </div>
    <div class="quote-author"></div>
    <a id="tweet-quote" class="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a id="tumblr-quote" class="button"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div id="new-quote" class="button">New quote</div>
  <footer><a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: When you mix css transition settings with jQuery animations you can run into trouble... Maybe try without the css transitions.

Comment: It won't have any effect on these two elements. The transition effect applies only on the `#new-quote:before`.

Comment: It's because `.show()` and `.hide()` methods set `display:block`, respectively `none` in the `style` attribute of the element, which overrides your CSS's specificity.

Comment: I've set their CSS to `inline-block` so after animation, they aren't gonna be on the `display: block` property.

Comment: You can set whatever you want in CSS. If, by any means, the DOM element has `style="display:none;"` it's going to be more specific. Unless you use `!important` in CSS, but than the jQuery animation won't work... Inspect your element after the jQuery animation has run and see the `style` attribute.

Comment: What is the reason for the hide() call in onclick? Without it, both divs  will be slid up and then down perfectly, isn't that what you want?

Comment: I just removed hide() call and the `$(".quote-container, #new-quote").slideDown(2000);` doesn't work because it needs an element to be hidden, or in other words, with the display none property.

Comment: You don't have to use `hide()` and `show()` methods. You can change any property you want, using the `css()` method.

Comment: Yea, I know. But it's quicker. In my opinion, the problem is using slideUp(), because in the first load, where slideUp() function doesn't exist, everything seems to work.

Comment: I was referring to $(".quote-container, #new-quote").css("display", "inline-block").hide(). You keep slide down

Comment: Wow, it really works.

Comment: Perfect........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem fixed**:

I needed to remove `$(".quote-container, #new-quote").css("display", "inline-block").hide();` line from the onclick event:

```
$("#new-quote").on("click", function() {
  $(".quote-container, #new-quote").slideUp(2000, function() {
    $(".quote-container, #new-quote").slideDown(2000);
  });
});
```